# Proprietary codecs in Blender

Tags: licensing

As far as I know, Blender includes **proprietary** codecs. That's why I have some doubts about its legal usage at work and making animation for my company. Can anyone explain me clearly whether this would be completely legal? Thanks alot in advance. Please don't give just "yes-no" answer.

Comment: What codecs are you concerned about? The jpeg avi is Blender's own and for the FFmpeg avi Blender uses own build that is configured to be GPL2 or later.

Comment: You know I don't understand much in it so if you tell me it's okay I'll be just happy. I mean such things like, say, codec H.264, containers Flash, MPEG. Are all of them free?

Comment: Looks like there are some royalties you should pay for commercial usage of H.264 of videos longer than 12mins. It's about $0.02 per video, will research this more.

Comment: Yes that's something like what I was reading about long ago somewhere in the Internet. On some forum people were discussing legal usage of codecs. with not much success, though...that made me to think over the issue..waiting for your ideas. Thank you

Comment: This is probably what Blender uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenH264. You could check with developers what exact version is used to be sure.

Comment: I got it. Thank you, Jaroslav. To sum up the things, I think I should make a conclusion that Blender less likely to use anything proprietary. We may don't know all of the details, like in your example, but I think otherwise they wouldn't have licensed it under GPL. Do you think I'm right with that?

Comment: Yes, I think so too.